# How to plot a line on the top of a grouped bar chart?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I have a grouped bar chart and I want to compare the values .i.e , I mean I want to visualize it using lines. I tried the following code and output is also follows

```
Y=rand(5,5)
str = {'A'; 'B'; 'C'; 'D'; 'E';};
bar_widh=0.2;
h = bar(Y,bar_widh);
hold on;plot(Y,'b');
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',str, 'XTick',1:numel(str))
grid on
l = cell(1,5);
l{1}='P'; l{2}='Q'; l{3}='R'; l{4}='S'; l{5}='T'; 
legend(h,l);
```

I got the following output:

[image]

I want to visualize smallest quantity /larger quantity of the bar.In some cases larger value is bad. Can you help me to plot the color of the line same as the bar

I got output as follows

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with your current output?

Comment: @m7913d The lines are not added to the top of bars but at A, B, C, D and E..

Comment: actually I want to visualise which is smaller

Comment: or can you help me to colour the line same as bar

Comment: You can set the bar color using h(1).FaceColor and use the same color to plot the lines (wherefore you should use a for loop)

Comment: @m7913d can you help me to write the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Y=rand(5,5);
str = {'A'; 'B'; 'C'; 'D'; 'E';};
bar_widh=0.2;

figure; hold on;grid on
h = bar(Y,bar_widh);

% to highlight the minimum of each group, 
% copy data into a new matrix
Y_ = Y; 
% find the minimum values and make the rest zeors
Y_(Y_~=repmat(min(Y_,[],1),size(Y,1),1)) = 0;
% then plot with so sort of highlighting
h2 = bar(Y_,0.5);

pause(0.1) % pause to allow bars to be drawn

% now go through each group of bars and plot the line
for i = 1:numel(h)
    x = h(i).XData + h(i).XOffset; % find the x coordinates where the bars are plotted
    ax = plot(x,Y(:,i)); % plot the line
    % set color of the bars the same as the line
    h(i).FaceColor = ax.Color; 
    h2(i).FaceColor = ax.Color;
end

set(gca, 'XTickLabel',str, 'XTick',1:numel(str))
legend('P','Q','R','S','T');
```

---

> `h(i).XData`

is the center coordinates of the ith group of bars.

For example, in your case:

```
h(1).XData = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]; % group P
h(2).XData = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]; % group Q
...
h(5).XData = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ]; % group T
```

> `h(i).XOffset`

is the offset value of each bar in the group from its corresponding centre coordinate.

For example, in your case:

```
h(1).XOffset = -0.3077; % group P
h(2).XOffset = -0.1538; % group Q
...
h(5).XOffset = 0.3077; % group T
```

---

Without highlighting the minimum values
[image]

Minimum values highlighted
[image]

Comment: It may be useful to summarise the key part of your solution and to provide a screenshot of your solution.

Comment: @Anthony is it possible to highlight the minimum first value of each group  of barchart (ie ist min among first bar of A B C D E

Comment: @user uploaded a new figure to show you the highlighted bars. They are thicker :).

Comment: @user what do you mean? can you upload a picture?

Comment: @user I don't see any problem. In group A, the blue, which is the minimum, is very close to 0 and probably barely visible, but it is still obvious from the lines.

Comment: 3 yellow thick bar and one violet thick bar.

Comment: @user Oh I see what you want. You want to highlight the minimum value for each colour, so for one colour there is only one bar highlighted. I will update the code shortly.

Comment: @user updated the code and example picture. Is that what you want?

Comment: @user How is it not working? is it giving you an error or it's not plotting what you want?

Comment: The only modification to the code I made was changing `Y_(Y_~=repmat(min(Y_,[],2),1,size(Y,2))) = 0;` to `Y_(Y_~=repmat(min(Y_,[],1),size(Y,1),1)) = 0;`, which should surely work.

Comment: thanks.now its working.can you help this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749834/error-in-extracting-values-from-bar-chart