# Error in extracting values from bar chart?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

```
d=[1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12;13 14 15 16]
bar_widh=0.2;
figure; 
h = bar(d,bar_widh);
for i=1:2:4
  for j=1:4
   x=d(i,j)
   y=d(i+1,j)
   figure,plot(x,y);
  end
i=i+1;
end
```

In this code I had plotted a bar chart and I want to extract values from bar chart. (Values are correctly extracted but only one point is plotted; not a line) But i'm getting wrong results.
My aim is to plot a line between

```
                                 d(1,1) and d(2,1);d(3,1) and d(4,1);
                                 d(1,2) and d(2,2);d(3,2) and d(4,2);
                                 d(1,3) and d(2,3);d(3,3) and d(4,3);
                                 d(1,4) and d(2,4);d(3,4) and d(4,4);
```

In first figure I need 2 lines(from 1 column); in second figure I need 2 lines(from 2 column); in third figure I need 2 lines(from 3 column) and in fourth figure I need 2 lines(from 4 column).
no.of figures=no.of columns

**Version 2**
I tried another version

```
d=[1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12;13 14 15 16]
bar_widh=0.2;
figure; 
h = bar(d,bar_widh);
saveas(h,'testfigure.fig');
clear
close all
h=hgload('testfigure.fig');
ch=get(h,'Children');
l=get(ch,'Children');
x=get(l,'Xdata');
y=get(l,'Ydata');
```

and i'm getting error as

```
Error using get
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Error in Untitled5 (line 10)
l=get(ch,'Children');
```

Comment: you should move `figure` outside the `for` loop and put `hold on` after it: `figure; hold on; for i = 1:2:4`. You might want to change  `plot(x,y)` to `plot(x,y,'*')`, otherwise you'll have difficulty to see what you have plotted.

Comment: to be honest, the quality of your question is quite low. I don't know what exactly you want to achieve. Ok, I understand you want to plot some lines using data from the bar chart, but what lines? What do you want the lines to look like? You can't just assume people will understand your definition of line and help you solve your question.

Comment: You got an error because `ch` does not contain a figure handle but you are using it as if it contains one.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It looks much better now. So, can I assume `d(1,1) and d(2,1);d(3,1) and d(4,1);` means a line between points `(d(1,1), d(2,1))` and `(d(3,1), d(4,1))`? That means you need four lines?

Comment: yes .in first figure I need 2 lines(from 1 column).in second figure I need 2 lines(from 2 column); in third figure I need 2 lines(from 3 column) and in fourth figure I need 2 lines(from 4 column) .no.of figures=no.of columns

Answer (score 0):

```
d=[1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12;13 14 15 16];
bar_widh=0.2;
figure; 
h = bar(d,bar_widh);
figure; hold on;

for i = 1:size(d,2)
    x = [d(1,i) d(2,i)];
    y = [d(3,i) d(4,i)];
    plot(x,y);
end
```

To plot a line, you must make sure the parameters `x` and `y` in `plot(x,y)` are vectors than scalars. For example, to plot a line between `P1 = [P1x, P1y]` and `P2 = [P2x, P2y]`, the paramenters should be:

`x = [P1x, P2x]; y = [P1y, P2y];`

[image]

Comment: put a figure before plot.i want it in separate figure.now I want the same color as that of bar chart.ie In the first figure first lines color must be same as the first bar of first group,second line color must be color of the first line of second group and  third line color must be color of the first line of third group and fourth line color must be color of the first line of last group

Comment: @user, I have demonstrated enough examples that can do what you are asking for. I think it is time for you to try it yourself.